# Is it fine to use miswak at start of wudhu?

Tags: wudu

With the help and blessing of Allah, I have started using miswak in wudhu. I use miswak at the start of wudhu. I want to ask that is it fine to use miswak at start of wudhu or I should use it when I clean my mouth (gargle)?

Answer (score -1):

you should use miswak before you clean your mouth (gargle) it is fine.